# react-router: Should a nested route render a child component of the IndexRoute's component or should it render a smart parent (IndexRoute) component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-router, single-page-application

My question is fairly simple. However, being new to React, and all of this routing stuff in general, I am unsure of how to use nested routes properly.

If I have a 'lookbook' page stored in a parent *Lookbook.js* component, I know that my IndexRoute will render *Lookbook.js*. Something like this:

```
<Route path="lookbook">
  <IndexRoute component={Lookbook}/>
</Route>
```

Let's say the Lookbook is a photo-feed and clicking on one of these photos opens a modal with the expanded photo and extra data. Let's call this expanded photo modal component *PhotoDetailsModal.js* (and it is a child of *Lookbook.js*). I want to create a route that will load the lookbook and open a specific photo automatically, thus enabling me to provide shareable URLs to specific photos.

**What is the proper way to accomplish the above using nested routes?**

My first unknown has to do with the route itself, would it look something like:

A)

```
<Route path="lookbook">
  <IndexRoute component={Lookbook}/>
  <Route path=":photoIdentifier" component={Lookbook}/>
</Route>
```

or

B)

```
<Route path="lookbook">
  <IndexRoute component={Lookbook}/>
  <Route path=":photoIdentifier" component={PhotoDetailsModal}/>
</Route>
```

Basically, for any of my dynamic nested routes, should I render the parent component *Lookbook.js* and just have it smart enough to notice that the URL includes a photoID OR can I somehow render the PhotoDetailsModal on top of the Lookbook explicitly?

Option B SEEMS closer to the best solution, however if I want to do all my data gathering in the parent Lookbook.js component, wouldn't Option A be better?

Looking for any insight into best practices for this kind of use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should scrap the IndexRoute and use a regular route to nest the modal.

```
// Routes
<Route path="/" component={Application}>
    <Route path="lookbook" component={Lookbook}>
        <Route path=":photoIdentifier" component={PhotoDetailsModal} />
    </Route>
</Route>



// Lookbook.jsx
class Lookbook extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {}
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>This is the look up page</h2>
                <h2>Renders a modal if children in props</h2>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: One question that I have in response to this answer is: If :photoIdentifier is the ID of the photo to be expanded, should I capture and use this ID in the parent Lookbook.js component, or should I capture and use it in the PhotoDetailsModal component? Furthermore, in which component should I check if the ID exists in the database and corresponds to a valid photo in the Database? I want to try and keep the data fetching in the Lookbook.js component, however it seems that with this answer Lookbook.js is somewhat ignorant of  how PhotoDetailsModal should render.

Comment: @connected_user I don't see why the fetching of the data would need to take place in Lookbook unless you are loading all the photo details initially and wanted to pass the data as a prop to the modal based on the ID. In which case you could check if children exist and if they do then pass the appropriate data and ID to the modal component.